# Any recommended ideas for getting logs from multiple servers with filebeat and logstash in ELK stack?

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk

In my office infrastructure has 3 server namely feature_server, develop_server and log_server. Both servers has currently running nginx service. That thing i want to do is how to possibly collect nginx logs from both of them using ELk stack (logstash and filebeats). It is already working for one server. Any kind of ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? You just need to install and configure Filebeat on the other servers the same way you did with the one that is working.

Comment: I've been trying to get logs from different services from different server. Services such as Nginx, mariadb and web applications logs. But the thing, the output from the kibana dashboard is not something I want (i.e. the log information are not clear enough). Is there some ways or recommended documentation to play around with logs from different services and send to one single logstash？ Btw, thanks for your reply @leandrojmp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install filebeat on both the servers and configure the filebeat output to send to single logstash instance. You can add additional fields as input from filebeat with different servers values and use that field in logstash to distinguish the logs.

```
filebeat.inputs:
 - type: log 
paths:
 - "/var/log/apache2/*"
fields:
 server_name: "feature"
 fields_under_root: true
```

You can also use that field as index when you send them to Elasticsearch from logstash.

```
Output:{
 elasticsearch {
    index => "logstash-%{[fields][server_name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }
}
```

All configuration depends upon how you want to see the logs in Kibana.